# How to remove random div js

Tags: javascript

http://prntscr.com/p9u6f9

I create random divs using:

```
let div1 = 'div_list';
let div2 = div1 + [Math.floor(Math.random()*24)];

node.setAttribute('id', div2);
```

And I want remove div using button, but how can I remove this, not having ID? Because the ID is random.

```
function remove() {
    console.log(div);
    let remove = document.getElementById(??????????);
    remove.remove();
}
```

Comment: where is the `remove()` function called ?

Comment: You need to save the "random" ids somewhere first.

Comment: Why are you using random IDs?

Comment: Which element is triggering the removal? Is it a child element inside each of the randomy divs?

Comment: Randomly generate the ids to remove. Wrap the removal in a try/catch and a loop.

Comment: give the divs you created a class and select a random one with class

Comment: How is remove called???

Comment: save the id of div you want and pass as remove function's parameter

Comment: I wannt remove exactly this div i click button on it, cos i generate div + button: http://prntscr.com/p9ucwa if i create static div like div_list it removes from top to bottom,  not clicked div.

Comment: Do you have any sage, and some wolfsbane? There's a spell for removal of random divs, but you need these herbs to cast it.

Comment: @KathilRoyal, let me ask you a question. What do you need the Id for, if you have a reference to the object itself? Like `node.remove()`

Answer (score 0):

Add an eventListener upon the creation of the node and call `remove` with the generated `id` :

```
let div1 = "div_list";
let div2 = div1 + [Math.floor(Math.random() * 24)];

node.setAttribute("id", div2);
node.addEventListener("click", () => remove(div2)); // add the event listener for the button of deletion if you're creating it with the div

function remove(id) {
  console.log(id);
  let remove = document.getElementById(id);
  remove.remove();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just try this example, it's 100% working.

```js
function randRemove() {
  var divCount = 5;
  var randNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * divCount) + 1;
  var randSelect = document.getElementById("div-" + randNumber);
  randSelect.remove();
  alert("Div Removed: " + "div-" + randNumber);

}
```

```css
.just-style {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 20px;
}
```

```html
<button id="randRemove" onclick="randRemove()">Remove Random Div</button>


<div id="main-div">
  <div id="div-1" class="just-style" style="background-color: red;"></div>
  <div id="div-2" class="just-style" style="background-color: blue;"></div>
  <div id="div-3" class="just-style" style="background-color: aqua;"></div>
  <div id="div-4" class="just-style" style="background-color: violet;"></div>
  <div id="div-5" class="just-style" style="background-color: forestgreen;"></div>
  <!--AND MORE DIV ... -->
</div>
```

Enjoy and good luck =D